# Is there anything equivalent to an access modifier that limits access to only one thread using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, access-modifiers

Basically, I'm curious if there is something that would make the following happen.

```
class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod() { }

    public void MyNonThreadMethod() { }
}

public void OtherThread(MyClass myObject)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(myObject.MyMethod);
    thread.Start(); // works

    thread = new Thread(myObject.MyNonThreadMethod);
    thread.Start(); // does not work
}
```

Regards, Anton

Comment: `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`

Comment: You can use a semaphore like waitone : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example, I assume you need to implement a method that can only be executed on a single designated thread. To achieve this, you could use a thread-static field to identify the designated thread – for example, by setting a flag from the constructor.

```
class MyClass
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    bool isInitialThread;

    public MyClass()
    {
        isInitialThread = true;
    }

    public void MyMethod() { }

    public void MyNonThreadMethod() 
    {
        if (!isInitialThread)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cross-thread exception.");
    }
}
```

Don't use `ManagedThreadId` for this purpose – see [Managed Thread Ids – Unique Id’s that aren’t Unique](http://rocksolid.gibraltarsoftware.com/development/logging/managed-thread-ids-unique-ids-that-arent-unique).